# Why can't apt find my desired version of iptables?

Tags: apt, iptables, ufw

I am trying to install version 1.6.2 of iptables in ubuntu 22.04. (Please note: This is about iptables 1.6.2.  I have no trouble installing iptables 1.8.7, but I need 1.6.2.)

```
root@924516f76c4c:/var/www# apt install iptables=1.6.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package iptables is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libxtables12

E: Version '1.6.2' for 'iptables' was not found
```

I don't understand the reference to libxtables12.  My motivation for installing iptables 1.6.2 is to address this problem when I try to use ufw...

```
root@924516f76c4c:/var/www# ufw status
ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Permission denied (you must be root)
```

I read that this error might mean I need to use iptables 1.6.2.

I have tried running apt update before doing the install, but that doesn't help.

Comment: What kind of env is that? Odd to see a permission denied as root, is it an openvz or container or some kind of chroot?

Comment: Ubuntu installed in a Docker container.  I wouldn't think that would matter.  So far, it hasn't impeded me from installing anything.

Comment: It matters because a container doesn't have it's own kernel and iptables is something that interacts more directly with the kernel. You need `--cap-add NET_ADMIN` to use iptables in docker.

Comment: You may be right, for all I know, but I have no trouble installing iptables 1.8.7 inside the container, with `apt install iptables`.  But I can't run `apt install iptables=1.6.2`.  I will update the question to clarify I am able to install iptables 1.8.7.  Not sure how to add `--cap-add NET_ADMIN` to an existing container.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t install `iptables` 1.6.2 using `apt` in Ubuntu 22.04 because it isn’t available in the repositories. Installing an older version of `iptables` is unlikely to fix your problem anyway.

Incidentally, you need to specify a *package* version, which includes more than “1.6.2”; for 1.8.7 you’d need to say

```
sudo apt install iptables=1.8.7-1ubuntu5
```

currently on 22.04, and if 1.6.2 were available, you’d have to specify the package version too.